# How to install your signal processor SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2?

Tags: c, c++

By default, user signals SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 terminate the process or thread. How to make them set their handler? I tried to read various articles on this topic, but since I am new to this topic, it was not possible to transfer for my needs.

And the need is the following - there are a number of producer threads (pthread) that execute a series of instructions in a loop and at the end of each iteration they wait for the signal (sigwait) SIGURS1 from the main consumer thread, and only after receiving the signal go to the next iteration. But due to completion by default, they are therefore completed.

Those. here we need only the fact of receiving these signals for the transition to the next iteration, and they complete the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of APis to set up signal handlers, I'll illustrate one of them:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void signal_handler(int signo)
{
#       define signal_message "Signal received\n"
        write(1, signal_message, strlen(signal_message));
#       undef signal_message
}

int main(void)
{
        struct sigaction new_handler = {
                .sa_handler = signal_handler,
        };

        if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &new_handler, NULL) < 0) {
                perror("sigaction");
        }

        pause();

        return 0;
}
```

The `sigaction()` function can install new signal handlers, its signature is:

```c
int sigaction(int signum,
              const struct sigaction *act,
              struct sigaction *oldact);
```

The first parameter is the signal number (e.g., `SIGUSR1`, the second parameter is a pointer to a `struct sigaction` structure with the handling details, the third is a pointer to a `struct sigaction` into which it will store the old values of the handler.  The third parameter can be `NULL` if you don't care about the old value.

One of the fields of `struct sigaction` is `sa_handler` -- that's a pointer to the signal handling function.  That function's signature must be:

```c
void function_name(int signo);
```

The function returns `void` and accepts the received signal number as a parameter.

Putting that all together, the example installs a signal handler for `SIGUSR`, then calls `pause()`, which will pause execution until any signal is received.  If I then deliver the `SIGUSR` signal to a process running this code, it prints `Signal received` to standard output.